# jQuery can't update elements generated by PHP, even with on.('click'

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo count($set); ?>; i ++){

    $('#inc' + i).on('click', function(){
        $('#scratchbox').val('test');
    });         

}
```

But what I need is this, which isn't working (the only difference is that '#scratchbox' has changed to '#set' + i):

```
for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo count($set); ?>; i ++){

    $('#inc' + i).on('click', function(){
        $('#set' + i).val('test');
    });         

}
```

Both the #inc divs and #set textboxes are generated by PHP in the same place and at the same time (technically, in this order: #set1, #inc1, #set2, #inc2, etc.). Also, further down I have this, which is able to retrieve the values contained in the #set textboxes just fine when the event handler is a static #submit div:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo count($set); ?>; i ++){
        sets[i] = $('#set' + i).val();
    }

});
```

What should I change and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time your `click` event handler runs, the value if `i` is set to its maximum value. Create an IIFE in your loop to save the value of `i` for each iteration of your `for` loop.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo count($set); ?>; i ++){
    (function (inner_i) {
        $('#inc' + inner_i).on('click', function(){
            $('#set' + inner_i).val('test');
        });         
    })(i);
}
```

Here's a good read on using an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression): http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Never heard it called IIFE....Always used the term "Closure"..  + 1 learned something new.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've got some reading to do. Will accept when able.

Comment: @John: FYI, the solution has nothing to do with closures (the closure is actually the problem). The solution is *scope*, which the IIFE creates. Whether the IIFE itself is a closure or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Why dont add class names to your elements so you can do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click_element', function() {
   var ID = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#set' + ID).val('test');
});
```

and have for loop separate that creates those click elements with the IDs.

Note that this solution is much faster in terms of execution than having to bind click events within a loop.